# AngularJS ng-grid inside accordion

Tags: angularjs, accordion, ng-grid

I am newbie in AngularJS so please accept my apology in advance if this seem like a noob question.

Find below the link to the plunker which will help you understand what i am trying to achieve. I have made few changes to what "jonricaurte" of Github had created. Basically i have ng-grid inside of accordion and the data source for ng-grid's is provided by $scope.dt and also each ng-grid has one editable column (column name 'Editable').

When i try to change value in editable column inside ng-grid it automatically reflects the same value in other ng-grid i.e. when i change value in Accordion A in "Editable" Column it automatically reflects the same value in accordion B.

So my question is how can i make changes in Accordion A without having any kind of impact on Accordion B.

I did all the google in world but with no luck. So please help me in any way possible.

Link : http://plnkr.co/edit/NQzDGTk5FWebBCtJ4Mbq?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems if you do not specify the field property for editable column, ng-grid stores row value in the same scope variable. I've forked your plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/BQAK1bJUqCWWEyVjYKUh?p=preview. Is it that want you are looking for?

That's the documentation for field option:

> The string name of the property in your data model you want that column to represent. Can also be a property path on your data model. 'foo.bar.myField', 'Name.First', etc..